# Extract specific information from multiple page pdf (and multiple pdf files from a folder) to CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pdf, accounting

I want to extract the following information from the attached sample pdf file.

1. Exporter/supplier Name
2. Customs Reference No
3. Country of Origin
4. Item Description
5. Invoice No
6. Assessment Date
7. Import/Registration Date
8. Taxable Value
9. Total VAT

to be done on multiple pdf files and they have the same per page format.

In this drive folder are my reference files - [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QjSkC3oiTGSwrOdCEurI9aCN9awOa1C-?usp=sharing'](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1QjSkC3oiTGSwrOdCEurI9aCN9awOa1C-?usp=sharing%27)

Currently, what I'm doing is using this code to save only # 1 to 7. I used pdfquery and pandas.

```
    import pdfquery
    import pandas as pd

    file = 'PDFproject/65140.pdf'

    pdf = pdfquery.PDFQuery(file)
    pdf.load()
    pdf.tree.write('pdfXML.txt', pretty_print = True)

    def pdfscrape(pdf):
    # Extract each relevant information individually
        IERD_ENTRY_NUMBER = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:overlaps_bbox("492.0, 763.85, 530.35, 773.85")').text()
        REGISTERED_NAME = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:overlaps_bbox("61.0, 773.884, 198.8, 781.884")').text()
        COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:overlaps_bbox("299.0, 609.85, 330.11, 619.85")').text()
        Item_Description = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:overlaps_bbox("69.0, 429.918, 245.382, 435.918")').text()
        Commercial_InvoiceNo = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:overlaps_bbox("112.0, 293.85, 179.83, 303.85")').text()
        RELEASE_DATE = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:overlaps_bbox("495.0, 227.884, 535.032, 235.884")').text()
        IMPORTATION_DATE = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:overlaps_bbox("424.0, 752.85, 515.74, 762.85")').text()
    # Combined all relevant information into single observation
        page = pd.DataFrame({
                            'IERD_ENTRY_NUMBER': IERD_ENTRY_NUMBER,
                            'REGISTERED_NAME': REGISTERED_NAME,
                            'COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN': COUNTRY_OF_ORIGIN,
                            'Item_Description': Item_Description,
                            'Commercial_InvoiceNo': Commercial_InvoiceNo,
                            'RELEASE_DATE': RELEASE_DATE,
                            'IMPORTATION_DATE': IMPORTATION_DATE
                        }, index=[0])
        return(page)

    # Loop to all pages and output to CSV   
    pagecount = pdf.doc.catalog['Pages'].resolve()['Count']
    master = pd.DataFrame()
    for p in range(pagecount):
        pdf.load(p)
        page = pdfscrape(pdf)
        master = master.append(page, ignore_index=True)
    master.to_csv('output.csv', index = False)
```

But this only works for pdf file with the same format on all its pages. I workaround with my multiple pdf files with pdfsam by extracting the 1st page of all my pdfs and merging all the extracted 1st page so it will be just 1 pdf file with the same format in all its pages. I cannot get data of #8-9 with this because it is from the other page of each individual pdf.

My goal is to parse the #1-9 (will be the columns of my csv) data from multiple pdf files (will be the rows of the csv) on a folder to a csv file (see excel file).

I'm asking here because I am totally new to coding and I'm stuck, I recently stared reading and watching yt tutorials to learn python application for accounting.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add your code to the question so we dont need to download a text file to see it?

Comment: Added the code on the question.

Comment: Hi Paulzzz! Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: It sounds like you are saying that you have working code, the issue is that the format of the tables in the PDFs changes page to page. In which case, maybe you can split each PDF file into pages, and group together the similarly formatted ones? You seem to have already done this for the first page of each one

Comment: Yes, it changes page to page. But the thing is, the succeeding pages are not the same in all instances. Like, for pdf 1, its page 2 might be same format with pdf 3, but not with pdf 4.

Comment: Do they have the exact same format? As in, could you use some identifying text in the pages to group them together? e.g. pages 1-2 in your sample seem to have named sections 1-69 - will they always be present? Can you use them as identifiers? The other pages have subheadings e.g. `Terms Of Payment`, `Assessment Notice` - could you check for those and perhaps some of the column names?